# how to configure jhipster with https

Tags: java, http, https, jhipster

I want to configure jhipster to use https.

I generated a certificate in the application parent folder.

I put this in my yml:

```
   port: 443
    ssl:
        key-store: keystore.p12
        key-store-password: password
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-alias: admodunet
       # The ciphers suite enforce the security by deactivating some old and deprecated SSL cipher, this list was tested against SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
        ciphers: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 ,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 ,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
        http2:
            enabled: true
```

I use this command to pack the application:
`mvnw -Pro clean package`

And this command to start the application: `java -jar app.war`

The application still starts on just in HTTP.

Comment: Please provide the filename of the yml files you are editing, along with what profiles you are starting the app in.  I don't recognize the `ro` profile from the build command

Answer (score 0):

For production package  u need for maven `./mvnw -Pprod` and for gradle it is `./gradlew -Pprod`

To package it `./mvnw -Pprod clean verify`